# python tkinter use button function to show string on entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

1. Intro: I want to use a button to get file path, then display the path on the entry
2. Question: I don't know how to display path on the entry, I search and try a lot yesterday, but all the things I try didn't work. I don't know which part is wrong, hope u can help me, thanks a lot.
3. My code here:

   ```
   class PageOne(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent, controller):
           ttk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent,text='video detection')
           self.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
           ttk.Label(self, text="video addr：").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=3, pady=5)
           self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=3, pady=3)
           ttk.Button(self, text='select', width=8, command = lambda: self.vid_sel_btn()).grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

       def vid_sel_btn(self):
           path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
           self.entry_1.insert(0,select_path)
   ```

Comment: please do not post pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the code.

Comment: thank u ~ I get it  ~ I will watch out for these details next time

Comment: Or, you could always [edit] this time.

Comment: I edited my code already .

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution just now, i changing 1 into 2

```
1.self self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self).grid(column=1,row=0,padx=3, pady=5)

2.self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self)
  self.entry_1.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=3, pady=5)
```